# connecting exim4 to openldap on remote server

Tags: email, openldap, exim, email-server, courier-imap

I have a server running qmail with about 300 user accounts on a ubuntu version 8 server.
I would like to migrate qmail to a new mta such as exim4.x. I have a VM setup using redhat enterprise version 6 to test the mail migration process. On my VM I installed exim using YuM and also installed courier-imap version 4.x from source. Both services are running. Using the maildirmake command on the VM server I created the exact same list of all of the Maildir directories on the qmail ubuntu (current mail server). I am assuming I can rsync all of the e-mails from the qmail server mailboxes to the new exim system?. on the qmail server openldap is also installed and configured. how can I make the accounts on the new exim VM server authenticate through the openldap server that is currently configured on the qmail server? is this something I need to configure through courier-imap or the /etc/exim/exim.conf file?

I hope I make any sense here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up `perdition` as a front-end proxy, which will let you move accounts across one at a time; if you do this, you can minimise the downtime and also make sure that your test account gets moved first.

You'll need to configure *both* the IMAP server and Exim to handle lookups in LDAP.

For Exim, in the main section set:

```
ldap_default_servers = ldap.server.example.com
```

then write an "authenticator" which uses `${ldapauth{...}}` to authenticate.  For instance, changing slightly an example from The Exim Specification, we have:

```
plain:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_prompts = :
  server_advertise_condition = ${if def:tls_cipher}
  server_condition = ${if and{{ \
    !eq{}{$auth2} }{ \
    ldapauth{\
      user="uid=${quote_ldap_dn:$auth2},ou=people,o=example.org" \
      pass=${quote:$auth3} \
      ldap://ldap.example.org/} }} }
  server_set_id = uid=$auth2,ou=people,o=example.org
```

Changes were to use PLAIN instead of LOGIN and restrict to TLS-only.  The ldap_default_servers is unused in this example; I think the URL can be dropped from inside ldapauth, and it's useful for some other queries to have it anyway.

I'm not expert in Courier, but I believe the documentation at http://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/README_authlib.html#authldap has what you need.